# Rails named relationship with same class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two classes like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :my_user, class_name: 'My:User'
end

class Mynamespace::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :user
end
```

The problem here is that from `User` i can get my_user object by `User.find(1).my_user`, but not vice versa:

`Mynamespace::User.find(1).user` ends up getting me same `My:User` object.

I have also tried this, but that does not work either.

```
class Mynamespace::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :user_parent, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end
```

Any advice? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did You really have a class 'My:User' or its just a typing mistake.? or its supposed to be MyUser?

Comment: You do not have a class called `My:User`. That is a syntax error. Please post your real code. Also, why do you have this tagged both Rails 3 and Rails 4? These are mutually exclusive tags.

Comment: Don't do what you're doing. Think of a better way to model your application.

Comment: sorry there was a typo, it is a namespaced class, it should be "Mynamespace::User".

Comment: The use case is that we have a user object, and also have a user object from a 3rd party lib, so put the other user object under its own namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `::User` to reference the model in the root namespace.

```
class Mynamespace::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :user, class_name: '::User'
end
```